# How to get F-keys of Apple Keyboard to behave like F-keys in Windows?

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp

When using an Apple keyboard in Windows using Bootcamp drivers, how can I change the behaviour of <kbd>F1-12</kbd> so that they are normally just <kbd>F1-12</kbd> and the special functionality (play, pause, brightness control etc.) is available using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1-12</kbd>?

Comment: Are you on Windows 10? It looks that OS may be having issues. Otherwise, it's probably a driver issue.

Comment: Windows 7. What issues are you thinking of? I think the OS and keyboard are operating as documented at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202676 but I would like to override the defaults wrt. function keys.

That is, have all function keys act like function keys, and only invoke the media/special functions with fn.